# Is it a bug that 'assert' ignores the current namespace?

Tags: php, exception, namespaces, assert

Should the following problem be considered normal behavior or a bug?

```
<?php
namespace Ns;

function func ()
{
    echo "Hello\n";
    return true;
}

func(); // ok
assert('func()'); // "Call to undefined function func()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert` I assume is behaving the same way as `eval` does in that it switches execution to the global namespace when the code passed to it is evaluated.  Specifying the namespace in the call works as you would expect:

```
<?php
namespace Ns;

function func ()
{
    echo "Hello\n";
    return true;
}

func(); // ok
assert('Ns\func()');
```

I would believe this to be normal behavior; `assert` is a built in function, and you're basically passing a string to it to be evaluated.  When execution passes to inside of the `assert` function, it would be in a completely different namespace (mainly the global namespace).

Comment: So `eval` ignores the namespace it was called from too and makes 0 mentions of "namespace" in the `eval` docs. Sometimes I wonder how PHP managed to become number one..

Comment: The issue is that the `assert` function itself exists in the global namespace.  when you call it and pass it arguments, then execution passes to it.  imagine calling an object method on an object that exists in a different namespace. once you are in the other object's method, then you are in a different namespace. its not that eval is ignoring it, it just has absolutely no visibility of it